# How to remove ad serving limit on Admob?

Tags: android, admob

I am facing ad serving limit on Admob account for more than 2 months. I have checked all the traffic but could not found any invalid traffic on my apps (as this was the reason most of the people mentioned for ad limit).

Please give an authentic solution of removing this limit.

If someone has done any measures which results in removal of that limit (other than removing ad units), please share.

Thank you

Comment: did you get the best solution ?

Answer (score 3):

Delete all your ad units from your admob console, remove the ad unit from your published apps also, wait for 7 to 8 days and the limit will disappear. After that stop your app users from side-loading your app, also if you display ads via firebase stop it and remove all firebase dependencies from all your apps and display ads without firebase, use frequency capping 1 ads per 6 minutes for the newly created ad units. Now add the unit in you app and publish to the Playstore. Thank me later.

Comment: what do you mean by sideloading? can you please elaborate?

Comment: should I remove firebase dependencies for ads only? or I have to totally remove firebase SDK from my app?

Comment: Sideloded version of your app means it is not installed from play store. Rather, it is installed from other third party site.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66719424/i-want-to-stop-showing-ads-in-sideloaded-apks-in-one-stack-overflow-answer-i-fo

Comment: You may look at my recent question because I am facing same problem from 1 month.

Comment: What is "remove all firebase dependencies from all your apps and display ads without firebase" means?

Comment: I was advertising my app through google ads and ads limit was placed on my account for invalid traffic, and later the account was blocked. Are we supposed not to advertise our apps